# Ajax data collection - Empty Set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call to a php query that I know returns results. However, I'm getting an empty set ("[]"). Here's my code:

```
var source = [];

// Get the user data to build the sources
function getUsers() {
    var data = $.ajax( {
        url: '/s/calendar_userdata.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(userData) {
            console.log(userData); // returns []
            var len = userData.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                source[i] = '/s/events.php?e=' + userData[i]; // error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"
            }

            return source;
        }
    });
}
```

I've done a lot of reading of StackOverflow and several tutorials on ajax calls and callbacks specifically. However, I'm stuck. Can someone show me what I've got wrong? I've been on this topic for the past 10 hours and am no longer making progress. Thanks.

Comment: well.. you do not specify a dataType so the default is text/html so userData is going to be a string, not an object or array, if your php is outputing json, then set dataType to json. And if your log is showing `[]` the actual brakets then your php script is just outputing an empty array.

Comment: dataType default is **Intelligent Guess** not *text/html*. It may vary for old versions of jQuery, dunno.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP script ('/s/calendar_userdata.php') is returning something, and, if the answer is yes, is it JSON formatted?

Comment: I updated the above code per your comments. I still get []. I'll take a closer look at the PHP. That PHP code ends with echo json_encode($results);, where results is the product of the query. I copied and pasted it from elsewhere, and it was working. More soon. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickEvans you were right. Bad query was returning an empty set. I'm getting data now. I feel like a heel. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's returning a body?

Maybe you could first do a
    curl -i {host}:/s/calendar_userdata.php
and post it as an edit.

Also, you could also get the status in the ajax call so you can assure you are not throwing useful information such as a 404 (NOT FOUND).

```
function getUsers() {
  var data = $.ajax( {
    url: '/s/calendar_userdata.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(userData, status) {
        console.log('userData: ' + userData + ', status:' + status); // returns []
        var len = userData.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            source[i] = '/s/events.php?e=' + userData[i]; // error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"
        }

        return source;
    }
});
```